# How do I create a custom 410 error page using the Django Redirect App?

Tags: django

I am redesigning a website with lots of old (and very poorly optimized) content. It doesn't make sense to migrate the old content, so I am using the Django Redirects App to raise 410 errors in case anybody discovers a link to the old website.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/redirects/

I am currently getting the default Chrome 410 error page. How do I deliver a custom 410 error page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the redirect app? A redirect should be done when the page has moved or you think you can take the user to a better experience (http to https for example).

If the page is gone, you should not redirect, but just return a `HttpResponse` with status 410.

You can wrap it in a [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function to specify a custom template, just be sure to pass a `status=410`.

Comment: Thank you! 

I was using the redirect app because I thought it solved my problem, but your solution is much better.